# Too Many rig layers (Rigify)

Tags: armature, rigify

[image]

I have two characters and two rigs. One character has already been generated with a rigify armature and the other is not yet generated. if I generate another rigify armature from the different rig, nothing appears, but instead it reselects the one with the already generated rigify armature and adds too many rig layers.

How do I delete this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by clicking the generate button again in the separate rig. It seemed to update the rig but you have to set the ik/fk again manually.

[image]